# How to write a smart push for mercurial, one that does a pull and merge before doing the push?

Tags: mercurial

I am looking to make some kind of alias for `hg push` so it will auto do a `hg pull`, `hg merge`, `hg commit` and `hg push` by itself.

Obviously if anything goes wrong, like conflicts on merge, it will stop.

So far I wrote this but it doesn't work when you do not have anything to pull:

`hg pull -u && hg merge && hg ci -m "merge" && hg push`

When you do not have anything to merge it will fail with:

`abort: there is nothing to merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An built-in extension named [fetch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FetchExtension) does all of that but push:

> In the simplest case, hg fetch acts like `hg pull -u` — it pulls changes from a remote repository into a local one and updates the working directory. (This is like the "update" command as found in Subversion or CVS.)
>
> If the pulled changes require merging, the fetch extension attempts an `hg merge` followed by an `hg commit`.

Enable the extension, then do:

```
$ hg fetch && hg push
```

Nevertheless, consider doing rebase (fast-forward merge) instead of a regular merge. This helps keeping the lineage clean from the endless "merge" commits, as is as safe as a regular merge if you `--keep` the original changesets.

As a matter of the fact, my usual workflow when working on a single task is like this:

```
# edit some files, test
$ hg commit
# edit some more files, test
$ hg commit
$ hg pull --rebase
$ hg push
```